# Character an off objects jumps back into T-pose after render

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging, keyframes, scene

I'm making a scene and i just need to render it. but every time i try the character and every other thing just jumps back into T-pose.. nothing works.. Pleas help. im starting to loose my mind..
Yes there keyframes on allthe bones.
I Tryied looking it up on the internet or looking at tutorials but non of them helped.
blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/jm4OxNWw

Comment: I downloaded your file, hit render F12, everything stays in place, no T-pose jumps. Blender 2.83.5.

Comment: hmm.. maybe it's somting is wrong with my blender..
I'll try to re download it again.
thx